# show that $T$ and $T^*$ have different eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the matrix $[T]_{E}^{E}$= $\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$

$V=\mathbb{R^2}$ with the standard inner product, I need to  show that $T$ and $T^*$ have different eigenspaces. so for $T$ it was easy I found the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ and its eigenspace is $SP{(1,0)}$

but now I am trying to find the eigenspace of $T^*$ for $\lambda=1$ and I don't understand how I should go from $T$ to $T^*$

Comment: By $T^{*}$, do you mean the conjugate transpose (adjoint of $T$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
$$
[T^*]_E^E = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The corresponding eigenspace of $T^*$ is $\mathrm{span}\{(0,1)\}$, which is not the eigenspace of $T$